# VB.Net DataTable Add Rows Work When Add Try Catch ex As Exception

Tags: vb.net, datatable

Currently I want to show data from `SQL` into `DataGridView` on VB.Net. But `Add.Rows` return `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` Error on my Project. So my original Code looks like this.

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Public DataTabel As DataTable
```

Assign Tabel for DataGridView

```
Sub Tabel()
        DataTabel = New DataTable

        With DataTabel.Columns
            .Add("kodebarang")
            .Add("namabarang")
            .Add("satuan")
            .Add("harga", GetType(Double))
            .Add("jumlah", GetType(Integer))
            .Add("hargatotal", GetType(Double))
        End With

        DataGridView1.DataSource = DataTabel

        With DataGridView1
            .Columns(0).HeaderText = "Kode Barang"
            .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Nama Barang"
            .Columns(2).HeaderText = "Satuan"
            .Columns(3).HeaderText = "Harga"
            .Columns(4).HeaderText = "Qty"
            .Columns(5).HeaderText = "Harga Total"

            .Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "###,###,###"
            .Columns(5).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "###,###,###"

            .Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
            .Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
            .Columns(4).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Columns(5).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight

            .Columns(0).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Columns(1).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Columns(2).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Columns(3).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Columns(4).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Columns(5).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter

            .Columns(1).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
        End With
    End Sub
```

Execute Add Rows to DataGridView from SQL

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Call Connect()

        Sql = "SELECT * FROM transaksi_partai where faktur_partai='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
        Cmd = New OdbcCommand(Sql, Con)
        Read = Cmd.ExecuteReader

        If Read.HasRows = True Then
            ComboBox1.Text = Read("customer")
            Label4.Text = Read("nilai_nota").ToString
            DateTimePicker1.Value = Read("tanggal_penjualan")

            Call Connect()

            Sql = "SELECT * FROM transaksi_partai_detail WHERE faktur_nota='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
            Cmd = New OdbcCommand(Sql, Con)
            Read = Cmd.ExecuteReader

            While Read.Read()
                DataTabel.Rows.Add(Read("kodebarang"), Read("namabarang"), Read("satuan"), Val(Read("harga")), Val(Read("jumlah")), Val(Read("hargatotal")))
                'Object reference not set to an instance of an object
            End While

            TextBox6.Enabled = True
            Button3.Enabled = True
            Button4.Enabled = True
            Button5.Enabled = True
            Button6.Enabled = True
            Button7.Enabled = False
            Button8.Enabled = True
            Button9.Enabled = True
            Label12.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Count
        ElseIf Read.HasRows = False Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End Sub
```

I change my code to this and its work fine without error. except if i enable the Exception

```
If Read.HasRows = True Then
            Try
                ComboBox1.Text = Read("customer")
                Label4.Text = Read("nilai_nota").ToString
                DateTimePicker1.Value = Read("tanggal_penjualan")

                Call Connect()

                Sql = "SELECT * FROM transaksi_partai_detail WHERE faktur_nota='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
                Cmd = New OdbcCommand(Sql, Con)
                Read = Cmd.ExecuteReader

                While Read.Read()
                    DataTabel.Rows.Add(Read("kodebarang"), Read("namabarang"), Read("satuan"), Val(Read("harga")), Val(Read("jumlah")), Val(Read("hargatotal")))
                End While

                TextBox6.Enabled = True
                Button3.Enabled = True
                Button4.Enabled = True
                Button5.Enabled = True
                Button6.Enabled = True
                Button7.Enabled = False
                Button8.Enabled = True
                Button9.Enabled = True
                Label12.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Count
            Catch ex As Exception
                'MsgBox("DataGridView Tidak Terupdate!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error!")
            End Try
        ElseIf Read.HasRows = False Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
```

Comment: Are you sure there is not a DBnull value that cause this error and not . DataTabel.NewRow?
Also before in your code was Dim DataTabel = New DataTable inside sub Tabel, that means it was a local variable and DataTabel outside global variable was Nothing??

Comment: yes, there is not DBnull Value cause this error. For `Dim DataTabel = New DataTable` inside sub Tabel, it;s my mistake, I tried change to it before but i return to original one `DataTabel = New DataTable`

Comment: I already edit my question where I add `Try Catch ex As Exception` but somehow it works without error. Still confused what cause my error though.